# How many Banelings do I need to wipe different structures?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-zerg

Wondering if I can find a list of how many Banelings you need to wipe common structures (supply depot, Command centers, pylons, Nexus, fences on the map, etc).

I know I could find out empirically but it'd be nice to know beforehand.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Banelings deal 80 damage to buildings.

Supply Depots have 400 health == 5 Banelings

Command Centers have 1500 health == 19 Banelings

Pylons have 200 health and 200 shields == 5 Banelings

Nexus have 1000 health and 1000 shields == 25 Banelings

Destructible Rocks have 2000 health == 25 Banelings

All numbers are approximate, as they do not take armor into account (which may mean you require 1 more baneling to make up for mitigated damage)

Comment: cheers - exactly what I was looking for! :)

Comment: Worth noting that its 80+5, so in the Command Center/Nexus/Hatch case, that upgrade saves you 1 Baneling.

Comment: what is their splash radius? if you hit a supply depot with a baneling, is the splash large enough to reach a building immediately adjacent?

Comment: @tzenes nice, thanks! @Matt interesting consideration, let's see what the experts come back with :)

Comment: Range is 2.2 and they do splash on building

Comment: So it's really not worth it to use banelings on say a nexus.  25 banelings = 16 roaches with gas left over, and 16 is a lot of roaches.  Workers are juicy though.

Comment: All workers are light, so you even do bonus damage.

Comment: @Davy keep in mind the speed at which banelings can hit... This is their advantage over the roach.  For instance if you nidus into your opponents main and their army is on the way, you can often do serious damage with banelings (almost instantly) where roaches do there damage over a longer period of time (allows scv's to repair and his army to run back)... As a recap, Banelings are one of the best blitz krieg attacks available, and can be used to get you ahead, or get you further ahead.  The cost of the banelings are easily made up for by the  time your opponent can't mine

Comment: @Aardvark just so you know, 25 banelings is 2500 gas/minerals to destroy a 400 mineral structure.  He'd have to have 21 SCVs Mining and no other bases before that becomes worth it.  By comparison, if you sent the Banelings directly at the SCVs you'd need 5-12 Banelings to set him back 1000 Minerals.  Based on SCV build rates, unless he had 5-6 Command Centers this constitutes a much larger loss in mining.  By comparison 25 Zerglings destroy a command center in 10 seconds and then can destroy all the SCVs...

Comment: Makes me wish for some good replays with drop play.